# Problems connecting to the Internet with NetworkManager

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, arch-linux, networkmanager

I'm using ArchLinux with Network Manager to connect to the internet through wifi, but sometimes, even if it is still connected to the wifi, I can't reach websites.
I searched a lot on the net to see where this problem comes from but couldn't find a solution.

When I ping my router or 8.8.8.8, it works perfectly:

```
$ ping -c3 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.28 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=1.42 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=3.01 ms

--- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.284/1.906/3.011/0.783 ms

$ ping -c3 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=10.3 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=9.96 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=55 time=10.4 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.964/10.218/10.423/0.190 ms
```

But when I ping google, it does nothing, or stop after sending one packet:

```
$ ping google.com
PING google.com (216.58.204.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C64 bytes from 216.58.204.110: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=10.9 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.874/10.874/10.874/0.000 ms
```

If I ping the IP address of google, it sends the 3 packets correctly:

```
ping -c3 216.58.204.142
PING 216.58.204.142 (216.58.204.142) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 216.58.204.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=10.4 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.204.142: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=9.74 ms
64 bytes from 216.58.204.142: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=10.5 ms

--- 216.58.204.142 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 9.740/10.224/10.512/0.344 ms
```

I thought the problem came from the file `/etc/resolv.conf`, but it is generated and completed automatically by Network Manager. I can't modify it, because all my changes are directly removed by NetworkManager

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Generated by NetworkManager
search home
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 2a01:cb08:8d09:bc00:46a6:1eff:fe24:e1e5
nameserver fe80::46a6:1eff:fe24:e1e5%wlp4s0
```

Furthermore, in NetworkManager, everything is set to "Automatically". How can I fix it? Is it a problem about DNS?